# Google Analytics measurement protocol not in report only in real-time

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I've got a chrome extension with a call to Google Measurement Protocol to register 'event's in Google analytics. Events are registered in real-time but do not appear in reports (also checked several days afterwards). I've tried something similar with 'pageview'. 
What could be the reasons for failure ? I've checked similar questions on SO with no clear solution. Checking with the Hit Builder does not provide any clue.

Typical parameters are :

v=1&t=event&tid=UA-xyxyxyxy-1&uid=be653208-154c-4924-88dd-66695804217f&dh=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.net%2F&dp=%2Fsgc&dt=Qwe%20Abc%20Dfg%20&ec=%2Favcdef&ea=abcddfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfd

Thanks for any help ...

Comment: What filters did you set on the view?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your call and it seems to work properly. Considering that you don't send the **cid** but the **uid** you can see the event in the **User-ID** view.